# What type of ferry boats were used in England in the early 19th century?

Tags: england, united-kingdom, naval, transportation

In 1800-1820, what sort of ferry boats were used by the general public in England and how were they powered? In particular I am interested in ferries used to access the Isle of Wight, and also whatever boats were used to cross the English Channel to France.

Comment: _OT: I misread "furry" :v_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [web sites that discuss the history of Channel ferries](http://www.theotherside.co.uk/tm-heritage/background/ferries.htm).

Paddle steamers made their appearance in the early 1800s:

[image: Bell steam boat]

Of course, every kind of boat could be used as a ferry, even small foot powered paddle boats. The 1827 scene below is from the United States, but the same kind of boats were used in the English channel:

[image: steam and sail]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Isle of Wight, but for the River Mersey  refer to...
http://www.lyricsfreak.com/s/stanley+holloway/runcorn+ferry_20307672.html